# Any two groups of three elements are isomorphic - Fraleigh p. 47 4.25(b)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The answer has no details. Hence maybe the answer is supposed to be quick. But I can't see it?

Hence I took two groups. Call them $G_1 = \{a, b, c\}, G_2 = \{d, e, f\}$.
Then because every group has an identity, I know $G_1, G_2$ has one each.
Hence WLOG pick $c$ as the identity in $G_1$. I want to match letters so pick $e$  as the identity in $G_2$.
Now we have $G_1 = \{a, b, \color{magenta}{c}\}, G_2 = \{d, \color{magenta}{e}, f\}$.

I know every group has an inverse. But how do I apply this to $G_1, G_2$ to simplify them?

And to prove $G_1, G_2$ are isomorphic, how do I envisage and envision what the isomorphism is?

**Update Dec. 25, 2013** (1). Answer from B.S. Why does $ab = b$ fail? 
$\begin{align} ab & = b \\ & = bc \end{align}$. What now?

(2.) Do I have to do all the algebra work for $G_1$ for $G_2$? Is there some smart answer?

**Update Jan. 8, 2014** (1.) I'm confounded by drhab's comment on Dec. 30 2013. Is drhab saying: Even if the domain's identity is the $\color{green}{third}$ letter $\color{magenta}{c}$  but the codomain's identity is the second letter $\color{magenta}{e}$, $d^{\huge{\color{green}{3}}} = e$ anyways? Hence I should've chosen the $\color{green}{third}$  letter in the codomain as the identity too?

What else is drhab saying about this?

(2.) I don't understand drhab's comment on Dec. 28 2013. Why refer to commutativity? It's not a group axiom? And what are the binary operations?

**Update:** I didn't realize this before, but by dint of Martin Sleziak's comment, this question is just a sepcial case of Fraleigh p. 63 Theorem 6.10 = Pinter p. 109-111 Theorem 11.1.

Comment: Have you already learned about cyclic groups? See
[Prime Group is Cyclic](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Prime_Group_is_Cyclic), 
[Cyclic Groups of Same Order are Isomorphic](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cyclic_Groups_of_Same_Order_are_Isomorphic) at ProofWiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's work on $G_1$ and assume $c=e_{G_1}$. So $$ac=a, bc=b,cc=c$$ But what about $ab$. It is either $a$, $b$ or $c$. If $ab=a=ac$, since $G_1$ is a group so we can cancel $a$ to have $b=c$ which is wrong because $b\neq c$. The same short story is when we assume $ab=b$, so we just have $ab=c$. This means that $$a=b^{-1}$$ and vise versa. Now what about $aa$? Is it equal to $a$, $b$ or $c$? We have $$aa=a\to a=c\\ aa=b\to aa=a^{-1}\to a^3=c\\ aa=c\to a=a^{-1}=b$$ The first one and the last one is clearly wrong so we just get $a^3=c$. Hence our group $G$ is change to the following form: $$G_1=\{c,a,a^{-1}\}$$ in which $a^3=c$. Now do the same way for $G_2$. It gives us: $$G_2=\{e,d,d^{-1}\}$$ What are the differences between these two groups? Just changing the alphabet $a\to d$ and vice versa? So, there are no differences between them and they are really the same things.

Comment: I think you meant 'in which $a^3=c$' (not $1$)

Comment: And I cannot really make sense of your last sentence. The fact that there is an isomorphism between the two groups should imply that you *can* change the alphabet in order to make the two groups the same (so why would the answer be no?).

Comment: @Dreamer: Thanks for that typo yes it should be $a^3=c$. In fact, I wanted to say there is no difference between these two structures. Sorry my poor English.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I upvoted. I updated my question. Can you please fill me in on them?

Comment: Dear @FrankMuer, when $ab=b$ then since $c$ is the identity element of $G_1$ so $b=bc$ and therefore we get $ab=b=bc=cb$. This leads us to have $a=c$ which is wrong here.

Comment: @FrankMuer: Why don't you reflect about drhab or Hagen's smart way? I see two approaches with different tastes.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try. And is there some smart answer to my update (2.)?

Comment: @FrankMuer: What do u mean by `symmetry`? :-) I think you got your answer. All we need for theses poor Groups has been done.

Comment: @B.S. Thanks. I meant a solution that just uses the work from $G_1$ and maybe changes some variables. Hence it is based on earlier work done and doesn't need any more work.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be a prime and $G$ a groups of order $p$. If $a\in G$ is not the neutral element show that the homomorphism $\mathbb Z\to G$ given by $1\mapsto a$ induces an isomorphims $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\to G$. Conclude that any two groups of order $p$ are isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Look at the Cayley table(s). Play some suduko.

(Doing it this way is no different from the standard proof that there is a single group of order two, up to isomorphism.)

Answer (score 1):

$a$ can only have order $3$ and the same is true for $d$. Then $\left\{ a,b,c\right\} =\left\{ a,a^{2},a^{3}=c\right\} $ (so $a^{2}=b$)
and $\left\{ d,e,f\right\} =\left\{ d,d^{2},d^{3}=e\right\} $ (so
$d^{2}=f$) and the mapping $a\mapsto d$ , $(b=a^{2}) \mapsto (d^{2}=f)$, $c\mapsto e$
is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks. I see the mapping is one to one and onto. But what binary operation does it have? I can't see why it's a homomorphism?

Comment: On the domain commutative ($x.y=y.x)$ and with $a.a=b$; $a.b=c$;
$a.c=a$; $b.b=a$; $b.c=c$; $c.c=c$. On the codomain likewise with
$d$ instead of $a$, $f$ instead of $b$ and $e$ instead of $c$.

Comment: It is a bit fuzzy, due to the fact that in the question the *third* element of the domain ($c$) was elected as identity against the *second* element of the codomain ($e$). That it is not smart.

Comment: In the group $\{d,e,f\}$ you have chosen $e$ to be the identity. The elements $d$ and $f$ have order $3$ so $d^3=e=f^3$. Then  $d^2\neq d$ and $d^2\neq d^3=e$ so the only possibility remaining is: $d^2=f$. That is not a *definition* (as you say in your edit) but a *statement*. What is your reason to choose the *third* letter (c) as identity in the domain against the *second* (e) in the codomain?? I can't think of any and it can cause confusion. That is why I call it 'not smart'. But that is only a notational matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please look at my update again? I'm still confounded by ths. And can you please move all your comments into your answer?

Comment: In comment of dec. 28 you asked for the binary operation. Answer: a.a=b ; a.b=c ; a.c=a ; b.b=a ; b.c=c ; c.c=c. Formally this is not complete, since the outcomes of b.a, c.a and c.b are not mentioned. To *make it complete* I remark that the operation is commutative. That enables you to find out for  yourself that b.a=a.b=c; c.a=a.c=a and c.b=b.c=c. As told before: forget the discussion about  second/third letter.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that any group with $3$ elements consists of just one generator, the inverse of this generator, and a neutral element (for otherwise it would not be a group). Therefore, there must exist a one-to-one correspondence between any two such groups.

Comment: @Mike This follows quickly from Lagrange (or some other basic named theorem - I always forget their names...)

Answer (score -1):

Write down a map of the sets, then prove that it is an isomorphism.  Bijectivity should follow from your construction.  So prove that it is a homomorphism.  Hint:  Order of the elements should help.

Comment: Not all bijections between the sets are isomorphisms.

Comment: Yes they are.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_homomorphism

Comment: You are confused. For example, clearly not every bijection between groups sends the identity of the first group to the identity of the second. Consider the map $f:\Bbb Z_3\to\Bbb Z_3$ defined by $f(x)=x+1$.

Comment: That $f$ is very clearly not a homomorphism.

Comment: Of course it's not. But it's a bijection between the sets.

Comment: Yea.  So like I said:  Bijectivity should follow, so prove that it's a homomorphism.  Bijective homomorphisms are isomorphisms.

Comment: You need to stipulate that the maps have to preserve the identity. This is what Alex is getting at.

Comment: @user1729  All group homomorphisms preserve the identity.

Comment: You said "Write down a map of the sets, then prove that it is an isomorphism". What you should have said is "Write down a map of the sets *which preserves the identity*, then prove that it is an isomorphism".