# Any two groups with three elements each are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is the proof of this problems concerned with Sylow theorem? I have no ideas to prove this.

Comment: It's way easier than that.  You can explicitly write down the isomorphism; in fact, you can scarcely fail to write down the isomorphism if you just try anything reasonably likely.

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617199/any-two-groups-of-three-elements-are-isomorphic-fraleigh-p-47-4-25b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $3$ is prime, any group of order $3$ must be cyclic. By the classification of cyclic groups, there is one one of these, namely $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to create a group of size 3 is to have an identity element, a non-identity element, and its distinct inverse.